# Cant execute a function with public synonym in oracle view

Tags: sql, oracle, roles, privileges

I have some issue with oracle privileges i do not understand. The environment where I need this is complex but I will describe on an smaller example:

---

There is a schema `math` with a function and a public synonym for it

**math**

-> function: `math.add`

-> public synonym: `add`

---

Then there is a role `mathematician` which includes the grant for the privilege to execute that function

**mathematician**

--> `grant execute on math.add to mathematician`

---

this role is granted to another schema `bob`

**bob**

-->    `grant math to bob`

---

**Now the problem**

I can use `add` in bob like `select add (1,2) from dual` but i cannot create a view in bob that uses `add`

trying so gives me:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges error
```

If I grant execute on `add` directly to bob `grant execute on math.add to bob` it works.

Its not the lack of create view privilege or something, also it marks the `add` as problem.

Would be great if someone can explain why this happens and lead me to solve this.

thank you!

Comment: "The owner must be granted these privileges directly, rather than through a role ..." when creating a view per the documentation. Where "these" is refering to the view's dependent objects. Please read over Alex Poole's answer to this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56189418/unable-to-create-oracle-view-accessing-another-schemas-objects-despite-grants/56189805#56189805. This should address your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much Patrick. I tried to find that on google and Stackoverflow with no success.

---

"The owner must be granted these privileges directly, rather than through a role ..." when creating a view per the documentation. Where "these" is refering to the view's dependent objects. Please read over Alex Poole's answer to this post, stackoverflow.com/questions/56189418/…. This should address your issue.